# Using a Lagrange multiplier to handle an inequality constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, quadratic-programming

so I was trying to do a very basic convex optimization example using the method of Lagrange multipliers. So I wanted to:
$$
\min f_{0}(x)=x^2
$$
$$
ensuring\space f_{1}(x) = x - 2 \leq 0   
$$
So I wrote the equation...
$$
L(x,\lambda) = f_{0}(x)-\lambda f_{1}(x)=x^2-\lambda(x-2)=x^2-\lambda x +\lambda2
$$
And then took the gradient...
$$
\bigtriangledown_{x,\lambda}L(x,\lambda)=\Big(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x},\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}\Big) = (0,0)
$$
...to get the two equations...
$$
2x-\lambda=0 \space and \space -x+2=0
$$
Which only seems to indicated that the solution is
$$
x=2
$$

But this is obviously wrong. So did I make an egregious mistake or does the method only work for more than one dimensional space or ....?

Comment: You treating the inequality constraint as an equality constraint.

Comment: I thought the Lagrangian equation was the same regardless- how should I have done things differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$2x-\lambda = 0$$ but we do not have $-x+2=0$ in this case because the constraint need not be active.

The right constraint is $\lambda \ge 0$ and the complementary slackness condition.

$$\lambda(-x+2)=0.$$

- If $\lambda=0$, then $x=0$. (The constraint is not active).
- If $\lambda \ne 0$, then $x=2$. (The constraint is active).

Comment: Ah, I think I see my issue. When it's an inequality I should calculate the gradient without a partial with respect to lambda since this is just a shorthand way of incorporating an equality constraint?

Comment: yup, taking partial derivative with respect to $\lambda$ would give you the equality constraint, but the constraint need not be active for an inequality.

Answer (score 4):

Introducing a **slack variable** $s \in \mathbb R$, we obtain the following equality-constrained [quadratically constrained quadratic program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program) (QCQP) in $x$ and $s$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x, s}{\text{minimize}} & x^2\\ \text{subject to} & x + s^2 = 2\end{array}$$

We define the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal L (x,s,\mu) := x^2 + \mu \left( x + s^2 - 2 \right)$$

Taking the partial derivatives and finding where they vanish, we obtain

$$\begin{array}{rl} 2 x + \mu &= 0\\ \mu s &= 0\\ x + s^2 &= 2\end{array}$$

From the 2nd equation, we have that $\mu = 0$ or $s = 0$. Let us consider each case:

- If $\mu = 0$, then $x = 0$ and $s^2 = 2$. This is the global minimum.
- If $s = 0$, then $x = 2$ and $\mu = -4$. This is at the boundary of the feasible region $(-\infty,2]$.

Comment: Is $s$ also considered when taking the derivatives? It does makes sense when you have either $\mu=0$ or $s=0$ from the partial derivative $\mu s =0$. Why the materials I have seen only take derivatives of $x$ and $\mu$ of $L(x,\mu)$, but then say there are two cases: "whether a slack variable is zero (which the corresponding inequality constraint is active) or the
Lagrange multiplier is zero (the constraint is inactive)"

Comment: Are the "two cases" concluded from $ \dfrac{\partial L(x,s,\mu)}{\partial s}=0$ like that in your answer?

Comment: @CyberPlayerOne Excluding linear programming (LP), I never studied inequality-constrained optimization.  This is based on my intuition. I do not know what people call these things. I use the term "slack variable" because of LP.

Comment: @CyberPlayerOne Yes, the 2nd equation is obtained via the derivative of the Lagrangian with respect to $s$.